# Why $\mathbb{C}[T_1, T_2]/(T_2^2 - T_1^3 - 1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[T, \sqrt{T^3+1}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is ring $\mathbb{C}[T_1, T_2]/(T_2^2 - T_1^3 - 1)$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[T, \sqrt{T^3+1}]$? I know the first one is the ring of polynomial functions defined on curve $y^2 = x^3 + 1$.

Comment: Can t you see how to define maps from one to the other which are inverse isomorphisms?

Comment: I see that map, which sends $T_1$ to $T$, $T_2$ to $\sqrt{T^3+1}$. But I don't know how to prove it formally that it is an isomorphism.

Comment: Find a map in the other direction and check that the two compositions are identities.

Comment: What do you think $\mathbb{C}[T, \sqrt{T^3 + 1}]$ means if it doesn't mean "$\mathbb{C}[T]$ adjoin a thing which squares to $T^3 + 1$" (namely $T_2$ in the first ring)?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan A possible answer to your question is that user42212 has chosen a nonempty open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{C}$, and a branch of $\sqrt{T^3+1}$ on $\Omega$, and then wants to study the ring of functions on $\Omega$ generated by $T$ and $\sqrt{T^3+1}$. (This is analogous to how some people would define $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ as a subfield of $\mathbb{R}$, rather than by formally adjoining a root of $2$ to $\mathbb{Q}$.) But, in any case, I agree that user42212 should think through and explain what he or she means by $\mathbb{C}[T, \sqrt{T^3+1}]$.

Comment: Well, my point in having him define the map in the other direction is that that would have sort of forced him to made precise what its domain is! :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Please consider converting your comments into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).